# File not getting saved

Tags: vba, excel

I get an error message: "PasteSpecial method of range class failed"

I guess this is happening because I am trying to paste something when there isn't anything on the clipboard (?).

Here's what I am trying to do:
1. Select the specified sheet "Test Sheet"
2. Paste only its values (without formulas) in a new file with a specific name

Here's what I get as output:
1. All values from "Test Sheet" copied into a new sheet named Book1 (contains only the one sheet with this name). Exactly what I want, without the file being saved.

Note:
1. I tried the file name method with a different set of code and it works, so getting the file name isn't wrong when it's working independently.
2. The file saving procedure also works when tried on a different set of code.
Seems to me that integrating the code with the copy-paste method is the problem.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test Sheet").Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
x = "filepath"
y = Range("B10").Value 'Reference of the cell which contains the value
If y = "" Then y = "Kawasaki Job"
Z = x + y
Z = Z + ".xlsm" 'Format of macro enabled worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Z, _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True     
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

After trying so many other things, I have realized I end up with one of these two outputs:
1. All worksheets copied in another workbook (with only values and no formulas) with or without an error message depending on the specific code I use.
2. Only the required worksheet copied (with only values and no formulas), but not saved (the problem I originally posted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. this should work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test Sheet").Copy
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    x = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    y = Range("B10").Value 'Reference of the cell which contains the value
    If y = "" Then y = "Kawasaki Job"
    Z = x & y
    Z = Z & ".xlsm" 'Format of macro enabled worksheet

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Z, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Same thing happens, but now I get a different error message:
"Select method of range class failed"

Comment: I tried this again and it worked. Marking this one as the answer. Also changed "Cells.Select" to "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test Sheet").Cells.Select". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:
`Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False`

To:
`ActiveWorksheet.UsedRange.Copy`
`Activeworksheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

Comment: Just realized the error...
Going by your method, all the worksheets are getting saved rather than just the one I specified. I have changed the ActiveWorksheet to ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("***") since it was showing an error otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The `Worksheet.Copy` method doesn't work like the other copy/paste commands, it does not use the clipboard. It just creates a copy of the sheet according to the options. The sheet, not the content of the sheet. See [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784(v=office.15).aspx) for details.

If you want to duplicate the sheet, use the `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test Sheet").Copy` method.

If you want to copy the values to a new sheet then you should do something like:

```
Set SourceSh = Sheets("Test Sheet")
Set DestSh = Sheets.Add
SourceSh.Range("A1:C10").Copy
DestSh.Range("A1:C10").PasteSpecial ...
```